# Answer Count not Appearing on Category Page

Tags: bug, questions, answers

I have noticed over quite some time that some questions appearing on the category page do not show any answer count to their left. When I click on the question and go to its page, I see a number of answers, some even with votes. The questions are sometimes half an hour before. What is the possible reason?

**Edit**

This is the screen shot of one such recent post. It does not show difference in answer count though it shows difference in votes.
[image: Category Page Pic]

And this is the shot of the original post.

[image: Post Page Pic]

Comment: Can you link to what you mean when you say "category page"?  It's not a term we use, and there are many question list sources...a link would be very helpful here.

Comment: For example when you click on the tag php, all newest questions come up in chronological order. I am talking about that.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php

Comment: Are you saying the element literally isn't appearing, or it's showing a 0 when there are answers?

Comment: Yes it is showing 0 when the answers are present, more than 1 and with up votes.
Pity i did not take a screen shot but i would next time. It has happened quite a few times.

Comment: i still see many posts with such behavior.

Comment: How old are these posts? that entire page is cached for 2 minutes, so some lag is expected

Comment: Well, certainly older than 2 mins. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641392/c-constant-structure-member-initialization
This post is 50 mins old, an it shows `-1` votes whereas actually it has `1` votes.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you see? and a URL as well, since I can't repro I need a bit more info

Comment: I have posted the screen shots. And sorry if they are that big.

Comment: I don't understand this. Both posts you show in the first screenshot have a non-zero answer count. Then you show a shot of a question cut before we can see if it has any answers or not. The vote count doesn't match, but that's volatile. ([the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641392/c-constant-structure-member-initialization)).

Comment: You are right. In fact, The point i am trying to tell is that the stats on both the pages do no match. I got this post with difference in votes at that moment. I would post the screen shot when i find some difference in answer count as well.
In a nutshell, my purpose of all this is just to help and not to point out unnecessarily. (If anybody gets this impression)